# How to make an Ubuntu LiveUSB for an non-UEFI system from within Raspbian?

Tags: ubuntu, bios, raspberry-pi, bootable-media

I need to make an Ubuntu LiveUSB to boot an non UEFI system from within the Raspbian OS. The PC's BIOS requires Legacy mode, and the LiveUSB I made will not boot that PC. The Rufus app will not work on my Raspberry Pi.

I tried making a LiveUSB with `dd if= of=` but the result would not boot the destination PC.

Comment: @K7AAY what do you mean with revising the question my english isnt good enough

Comment: You did OK. The Markdown language https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax used here to edit questions is not entirely intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of dd is very fussy. Please start in the directory where the Ubuntu ISO file is, and try

```
dd if=ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=2MB && sync
```

If the ISO is not named: **ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop.iso**
Please change the name in the command line

If the USB flash drive you want to make into a LiveUSB is not **/dev/sdb**
please change its name in the command line

Should that fail, try the ARM version of [Etcher](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-arm).

Comment: Thank you my pc booted to the Ubuntu screen